# How can I change the content of a section of a webpage to display another section based on successful form submission?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a section in my web app that contains a form for users to subscribe to a newsletter. I am using Mailchimp to store the list of subscribers who signed via my site. All's working well and so far so good (BTW, I am using the mailchimp API to add subscribers from my site to the audience list on Mailchimp).

There is a single field in the newsletter section that is for collecting an email address. What I want to do is this: once the user submits the form, stay on the same page (afterall, this section is part of the homepage and there are other sections there), but display a successful message.

I have been looking at things and I could (a) disable the textbox and display a success message in it, (b) change the entire section to no longer show the textbox but the success message (using partial views) or simply display a message somewhere above or below the current textbox giving the indication that form submission was succesful. I'd prefer to go with partials and just return a completely different view in that section with the confirmation message (next time the use relaods, it's fine for the textbox to reappear).

So my question is how do I change the section to pull in another view (while removing the existing view) on successful form submission?

Note: I have been looking at so many clues and they include querystrings, rendering different partials using razor in the html page, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. I am using TempData and Razor - OnPost, I store the success message in TempData and redirect to `./Index`. From there, I check to make sure TempData is not null (`TempData.Peek()`) and then display the message. That's working already. I could leave it like this or enhance it by using the value of TempData to determine the partial to render.